# Is there any way to read the settings Computer Local Policy Settings?

Tags: windows, group-policy

I'm trying to read the local group policies applied on the local machine.
Policies which are there in `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates`. I'm getting these policies from the `Registry`,
but I want to read the settings of each policy like in:
`WindowsSettings\SecuritySettings\LocalPolicies\AuditPolicy`.

Is there any possible way to read settings from scripts, `WMI`, `PowerShell`, or `C#`?